# make failure installing monit on linux ec2

Tags: linux, monit

I'm trying to install monit on linux. I ran the following commands :

```
wget http://mmonit.com/monit/dist/monit-5.5.tar.gz
tar zxvf monit-5.5.tar.gz
cd monit-5.5
./configure
```

and when i try :

```
make && make install
```

I get :

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

monit-5.5 directory contains the following :

```
$ ls
CHANGES      Makefile.in  bootstrap   configure     doc       monitrc
COPYING      README       config      configure.ac  libmonit  src
Makefile.am  aclocal.m4   config.log  contrib       monit.1
```

don't know what's the problem. thank you for your help.

```
[ec2-user@...~]$ sudo tar zxvf monit-5.5.tar.gz.1 monit-5.5/
monit-5.5/src/
monit-5.5/src/http/
monit-5.5/src/http/base64.h
monit-5.5/src/http/processor.h
monit-5.5/src/http/base64.c
monit-5.5/src/http/cervlet.c
monit-5.5/src/http/cervlet.h
monit-5.5/src/http/engine.h
monit-5.5/src/http/engine.c
monit-5.5/src/http/processor.c
monit-5.5/src/http/httpstatus.h
monit-5.5/src/p.y
monit-5.5/src/collector.c
monit-5.5/src/util.h
monit-5.5/src/ssl.c
monit-5.5/src/status.c
monit-5.5/src/monit.h
monit-5.5/src/log.c
monit-5.5/src/net.c
monit-5.5/src/y.tab.c
monit-5.5/src/file.h
monit-5.5/src/socket.h
monit-5.5/src/md5_crypt.c
monit-5.5/src/event.c
monit-5.5/src/md5.c
monit-5.5/src/daemonize.c
monit-5.5/src/signal.c
monit-5.5/src/process.h
monit-5.5/src/sha1.c
monit-5.5/src/lex.yy.c
monit-5.5/src/md5_crypt.h
monit-5.5/src/socket.c
monit-5.5/src/control.c
monit-5.5/src/config.h.in
monit-5.5/src/net.h
monit-5.5/src/env.c
monit-5.5/src/util.c
monit-5.5/src/alert.c
monit-5.5/src/l.l
monit-5.5/src/state.c
monit-5.5/src/alert.h
monit-5.5/src/md5.h
monit-5.5/src/http.c
monit-5.5/src/validate.c
monit-5.5/src/process.c
monit-5.5/src/gc.c
monit-5.5/src/device/
monit-5.5/src/device/device_sysdep.h
monit-5.5/src/device/sysdep_LINUX.c
monit-5.5/src/device/sysdep_NETBSD.c
monit-5.5/src/device/device.h
monit-5.5/src/device/sysdep_DARWIN.c
monit-5.5/src/device/sysdep_OPENBSD.c
monit-5.5/src/device/sysdep_UNKNOWN.c
monit-5.5/src/device/sysdep_SOLARIS.c
monit-5.5/src/device/device_common.c
monit-5.5/src/device/sysdep_AIX.c
monit-5.5/src/device/sysdep_FREEBSD.c
monit-5.5/src/device/sysdep_HPUX.c
monit-5.5/src/tokens.h
monit-5.5/src/state.h
monit-5.5/src/file.c
monit-5.5/src/spawn.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/
monit-5.5/src/protocols/rsync.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/pgsql.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/mysql.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/ftp.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/protocol.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/apache_status.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/lmtp.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/dns.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/ntp3.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/sip.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/nntp.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/tns.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/ldap2.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/smtp.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/ldap3.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/radius.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/http.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/dwp.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/imap.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/default.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/gps.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/protocol.h
monit-5.5/src/protocols/pop.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/generic.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/ssh.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/memcache.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/clamav.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/postfix_policy.c
monit-5.5/src/protocols/rdate.c
monit-5.5/src/event.h
monit-5.5/src/xml.c
monit-5.5/src/ssl.h
monit-5.5/src/sha1.h
monit-5.5/src/process/
monit-5.5/src/process/sysdep_LINUX.c
monit-5.5/src/process/sysdep_NETBSD.c
monit-5.5/src/process/sysdep_DARWIN.c
monit-5.5/src/process/sysdep_OPENBSD.c
monit-5.5/src/process/sysdep_UNKNOWN.c
monit-5.5/src/process/process_sysdep.h
monit-5.5/src/process/process_common.c
monit-5.5/src/process/sysdep_SOLARIS.c
monit-5.5/src/process/sysdep_AIX.c
monit-5.5/src/process/sysdep_FREEBSD.c
monit-5.5/src/process/sysdep_HPUX.c
monit-5.5/src/sendmail.c
monit-5.5/src/monit.c
monit-5.5/monitrc
monit-5.5/CHANGES
monit-5.5/monit.1
monit-5.5/configure.ac
monit-5.5/configure
monit-5.5/aclocal.m4
monit-5.5/Makefile.in
monit-5.5/bootstrap
monit-5.5/libmonit/
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/thread/
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/thread/Thread.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/thread/Thread.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/system/
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/system/Time.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/system/Net.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/system/Mem.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/system/Mem.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/system/Net.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/system/System.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/system/Command.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/system/Time.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/system/System.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/system/Process.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/system/Command.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/io/
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/io/File.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/io/Dir.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/io/InputStream.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/io/InputStream.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/io/OutputStream.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/io/OutputStream.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/io/File.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/io/Dir.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/util/
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/util/Str.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/util/Str.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/util/StringBuffer.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/util/StringBuffer.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/util/List.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/util/List.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/xconfig.h.in
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/Bootstrap.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/Bootstrap.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/exceptions/
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/exceptions/MemoryException.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/exceptions/AssertException.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/exceptions/Exception.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/exceptions/NumberFormatException.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/exceptions/IOException.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/exceptions/assert.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/exceptions/Exception.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/exceptions/assert.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/src/Config.h
monit-5.5/libmonit/libtool
monit-5.5/libmonit/Makefile
monit-5.5/libmonit/configure.ac
monit-5.5/libmonit/test/
monit-5.5/libmonit/test/OutputStreamTest.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/test/Makefile
monit-5.5/libmonit/test/FileTest.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/test/StrTest.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/test/TimeTest.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/test/CommandTest.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/test/Makefile.in
monit-5.5/libmonit/test/ListTest.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/test/DirTest.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/test/NetTest.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/test/test.sh
monit-5.5/libmonit/test/StringBufferTest.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/test/ExceptionTest.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/test/Makefile.am
monit-5.5/libmonit/test/SystemTest.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/test/InputStreamTest.c
monit-5.5/libmonit/test/data/
monit-5.5/libmonit/test/data/stream.data
monit-5.5/libmonit/configure
monit-5.5/libmonit/aclocal.m4
monit-5.5/libmonit/Makefile.in
monit-5.5/libmonit/bootstrap
monit-5.5/libmonit/config/
monit-5.5/libmonit/config/config.guess
monit-5.5/libmonit/config/missing
monit-5.5/libmonit/config/ltmain.sh
monit-5.5/libmonit/config/install-sh
monit-5.5/libmonit/config/config.sub
monit-5.5/libmonit/COPYING
monit-5.5/libmonit/README
monit-5.5/libmonit/Makefile.am
monit-5.5/libmonit/m4/
monit-5.5/libmonit/m4/libtool.m4
monit-5.5/libmonit/m4/lt~obsolete.m4
monit-5.5/libmonit/m4/ltsugar.m4
monit-5.5/libmonit/m4/ltoptions.m4
monit-5.5/libmonit/m4/ltversion.m4
monit-5.5/contrib/
monit-5.5/contrib/monitrc-gentoo
monit-5.5/contrib/rc.monit
monit-5.5/contrib/packages/
monit-5.5/contrib/packages/freebsd/
monit-5.5/contrib/packages/freebsd/pkg-message
monit-5.5/contrib/packages/freebsd/distinfo
monit-5.5/contrib/packages/freebsd/Makefile
monit-5.5/contrib/packages/freebsd/files/
monit-5.5/contrib/packages/freebsd/files/monit.sh
monit-5.5/contrib/packages/freebsd/pkg-descr
monit-5.5/contrib/packages/freebsd/README.porter
monit-5.5/contrib/packages/redhat/
monit-5.5/contrib/packages/redhat/monit.spec
monit-5.5/contrib/packages/solaris/
monit-5.5/contrib/packages/solaris/README.solaris
monit-5.5/contrib/packages/solaris/init.monit
monit-5.5/contrib/packages/solaris/makesolpkg.sh
monit-5.5/contrib/monit.upstart.in
monit-5.5/contrib/monit.service.in
monit-5.5/contrib/monit.service
monit-5.5/contrib/monit.upstart
monit-5.5/config/
monit-5.5/config/config.guess
monit-5.5/config/missing
monit-5.5/config/ltmain.sh
monit-5.5/config/install-sh
monit-5.5/config/config.sub
monit-5.5/COPYING
monit-5.5/README
monit-5.5/doc/
monit-5.5/doc/monit.pod
monit-5.5/doc/PLATFORMS
monit-5.5/Makefile.am
[ec2-user@domU-12-31-39-03-28-A1 ~]$ ls
crawller                    monit-5.5           node-v0.8.14         tmp
m_2.2.0.tgz                 monit-5.5.tar.gz    node-v0.8.14.tar.gz
mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.2.0  monit-5.5.tar.gz.1  nodejs
[ec2-user@domU-12-31-39-03-28-A1 ~]$ cd monit-5.5
[ec2-user@domU-12-31-39-03-28-A1 monit-5.5]$ sudo ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... none
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for flex... /usr/bin/flex
checking for pod2man... /usr/bin/pod2man
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for socket in -lsocket... no
checking for socket in -linet... no
checking for inet_addr in -lnsl... yes
checking for inet_aton in -lresolv... yes
checking for crypt in -lc... no
checking for crypt in -lcrypt... yes
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking whether stat file-mode macros are broken... no
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking alloca.h usability... yes
checking alloca.h presence... yes
checking for alloca.h... yes
checking arpa/inet.h usability... yes
checking arpa/inet.h presence... yes
checking for arpa/inet.h... yes
checking asm/page.h usability... no
checking asm/page.h presence... no
checking for asm/page.h... no
checking asm/param.h usability... yes
checking asm/param.h presence... yes
checking for asm/param.h... yes
checking cf.h usability... no
checking cf.h presence... no
checking for cf.h... no
checking crt_externs.h usability... no
checking crt_externs.h presence... no
checking for crt_externs.h... no
checking ctype.h usability... yes
checking ctype.h presence... yes
checking for ctype.h... yes
checking crypt.h usability... yes
checking crypt.h presence... yes
checking for crypt.h... yes
checking dirent.h usability... yes
checking dirent.h presence... yes
checking for dirent.h... yes
checking errno.h usability... yes
checking errno.h presence... yes
checking for errno.h... yes
checking execinfo.h usability... yes
checking execinfo.h presence... yes
checking for execinfo.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking getopt.h usability... yes
checking getopt.h presence... yes
checking for getopt.h... yes
checking glob.h usability... yes
checking glob.h presence... yes
checking for glob.h... yes
checking grp.h usability... yes
checking grp.h presence... yes
checking for grp.h... yes
checking kvm.h usability... no
checking kvm.h presence... no
checking for kvm.h... no
checking paths.h usability... yes
checking paths.h presence... yes
checking for paths.h... yes
checking kstat.h usability... no
checking kstat.h presence... no
checking for kstat.h... no
checking sys/protosw.h usability... no
checking sys/protosw.h presence... no
checking for sys/protosw.h... no
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking loadavg.h usability... no
checking loadavg.h presence... no
checking for loadavg.h... no
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking mach/host_info.h usability... no
checking mach/host_info.h presence... no
checking for mach/host_info.h... no
checking mach/mach.h usability... no
checking mach/mach.h presence... no
checking for mach/mach.h... no
checking mach/mach_host.h usability... no
checking mach/mach_host.h presence... no
checking for mach/mach_host.h... no
checking for memory.h... (cached) yes
checking mntent.h usability... yes
checking mntent.h presence... yes
checking for mntent.h... yes
checking netdb.h usability... yes
checking netdb.h presence... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking netinet/in.h usability... yes
checking netinet/in.h presence... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking netinet/in_systm.h usability... yes
checking netinet/in_systm.h presence... yes
checking for netinet/in_systm.h... yes
checking pam/pam_appl.h usability... no
checking pam/pam_appl.h presence... no
checking for pam/pam_appl.h... no
checking security/pam_appl.h usability... no
checking security/pam_appl.h presence... no
checking for security/pam_appl.h... no
checking poll.h usability... yes
checking poll.h presence... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking procfs.h usability... no
checking procfs.h presence... no
checking for procfs.h... no
checking sys/procfs.h usability... yes
checking sys/procfs.h presence... yes
checking for sys/procfs.h... yes
checking procinfo.h usability... no
checking procinfo.h presence... no
checking for procinfo.h... no
checking pthread.h usability... yes
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking pwd.h usability... yes
checking pwd.h presence... yes
checking for pwd.h... yes
checking regex.h usability... yes
checking regex.h presence... yes
checking for regex.h... yes
checking setjmp.h usability... yes
checking setjmp.h presence... yes
checking for setjmp.h... yes
checking signal.h usability... yes
checking signal.h presence... yes
checking for signal.h... yes
checking stdarg.h usability... yes
checking stdarg.h presence... yes
checking for stdarg.h... yes
checking stddef.h usability... yes
checking stddef.h presence... yes
checking for stddef.h... yes
checking stdio.h usability... yes
checking stdio.h presence... yes
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking stropts.h usability... no
checking stropts.h presence... no
checking for stropts.h... no
checking sys/cfgodm.h usability... no
checking sys/cfgodm.h presence... no
checking for sys/cfgodm.h... no
checking sys/cfgdb.h usability... no
checking sys/cfgdb.h presence... no
checking for sys/cfgdb.h... no
checking sys/dk.h usability... no
checking sys/dk.h presence... no
checking for sys/dk.h... no
checking sys/dkstat.h usability... no
checking sys/dkstat.h presence... no
checking for sys/dkstat.h... no
checking sys/filio.h usability... no
checking sys/filio.h presence... no
checking for sys/filio.h... no
checking sys/ioctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking sys/loadavg.h usability... no
checking sys/loadavg.h presence... no
checking for sys/loadavg.h... no
checking sys/lock.h usability... no
checking sys/lock.h presence... no
checking for sys/lock.h... no
checking sys/mnttab.h usability... no
checking sys/mnttab.h presence... no
checking for sys/mnttab.h... no
checking sys/mutex.h usability... no
checking sys/mutex.h presence... no
checking for sys/mutex.h... no
checking sys/nlist.h usability... no
checking sys/nlist.h presence... no
checking for sys/nlist.h... no
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking sys/pstat.h usability... no
checking sys/pstat.h presence... no
checking for sys/pstat.h... no
checking sys/queue.h usability... yes
checking sys/queue.h presence... yes
checking for sys/queue.h... yes
checking sys/resource.h usability... yes
checking sys/resource.h presence... yes
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
checking sys/statfs.h usability... yes
checking sys/statfs.h presence... yes
checking for sys/statfs.h... yes
checking sys/statvfs.h usability... yes
checking sys/statvfs.h presence... yes
checking for sys/statvfs.h... yes
checking sys/sysinfo.h usability... yes
checking sys/sysinfo.h presence... yes
checking for sys/sysinfo.h... yes
checking sys/systemcfg.h usability... no
checking sys/systemcfg.h presence... no
checking for sys/systemcfg.h... no
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking sys/tree.h usability... no
checking sys/tree.h presence... no
checking for sys/tree.h... no
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/un.h usability... yes
checking sys/un.h presence... yes
checking for sys/un.h... yes
checking sys/utsname.h usability... yes
checking sys/utsname.h presence... yes
checking for sys/utsname.h... yes
checking sys/vmmeter.h usability... no
checking sys/vmmeter.h presence... no
checking for sys/vmmeter.h... no
checking sys/vfs.h usability... yes
checking sys/vfs.h presence... yes
checking for sys/vfs.h... yes
checking syslog.h usability... yes
checking syslog.h presence... yes
checking for syslog.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking uvm/uvm.h usability... no
checking uvm/uvm.h presence... no
checking for uvm/uvm.h... no
checking uvm/uvm_extern.h usability... no
checking uvm/uvm_extern.h presence... no
checking for uvm/uvm_extern.h... no
checking vm/vm.h usability... no
checking vm/vm.h presence... no
checking for vm/vm.h... no
checking for libperfstat.h... no
checking for netinet/ip.h... yes
checking for net/if.h... yes
checking for netinet/ip_icmp.h... yes
checking for sys/sysctl.h... yes
checking for sys/mount.h... yes
checking for sys/proc.h... no
checking for sys/swap.h... yes
checking for sys/ucred.h... no
checking for sys/user.h... yes
checking for machine/vmparam.h... no
checking for vm/pmap.h... no
checking for machine/pmap.h... no
checking for vm/vm_map.h... no
checking for vm/vm_object.h... no
checking for sys/resourcevar.h... no
checking for uvm/uvm_map.h... no
checking for uvm/uvm_pmap.h... no
checking for uvm/uvm_object.h... no
checking for mode_t... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for pid_t... (cached) yes
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking for struct tm.tm_gmtoff... no
checking for error_at_line... yes
checking vfork.h usability... no
checking vfork.h presence... no
checking for vfork.h... no
checking for fork... yes
checking for vfork... yes
checking for working fork... yes
checking for working vfork... (cached) yes
checking whether lstat correctly handles trailing slash... yes
checking whether stat accepts an empty string... no
checking for strftime... yes
checking for statfs... yes
checking for statvfs... yes
checking for setlocale... yes
checking for getaddrinfo... yes
checking for syslog... yes
checking for vsyslog... yes
checking for backtrace... yes
checking for getloadavg... yes
checking for SOL_IP... yes
checking for va_copy... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking pid file location... /var/run
checking for large files support... enabled
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for PAM support... enabled
checking for pam_start in -lpam... no
configure: error: PAM enabled but headers or library not found, install the PAM development support or run configure --without-pam
[ec2-user@... monit-5.5]$ make && make install
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thank you very much, you were right, the problem was I didn't have pam and ssl headers installed
So what I did that solved the problem :

```
sudo -s
sudo yum install pam-devel
sudo yum install openssl-devel
sudo yum update (probably not necessary but to be on the sife side)
```

then, I had problems with the monitrc file so i copied it to ~ and

```
chmod 0700 ~/.monitrc
```

Comment: In Ubuntu, using apt-get, the library names differs a bit:

`sudo apt-get install libpam0g-dev` and 
`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

Comment: more on ubuntu, I needed these in there to point to a few things: ./configure --prefix=/usr/sbin --bindir=/usr/sbin --sysconfdir=/etc/monit/ --with-ssl-lib-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Answer (score 3):

I ended up to this question trying to figure out the same issue on Debian. So here is what I needed to do to get it working on Debian.

```
#Install dependencies and required tools
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libpam0g-dev gcc make 

# CHECK LATEST MONIT VERSION http://mmonit.com/monit/dist/
wget http://mmonit.com/monit/dist/monit-5.12.2.tar.gz
tar xzvf monit-5.12.2.tar.gz
cd monit-5.12.2/
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/sbin --bindir=/usr/sbin --sysconfdir=/etc/monit/
sudo make
sudo make install
```

I needed to install libssl-dev and libpam0g-dev to make it work. I also added some options to configure to make it match the usual locations.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have installed all of the required dependencies needed to build Monit. After some research I couldn't turn up what they are, but they are probably in the documentation. Of course, after you get that figured out, re-extract the tar archive to refresh the contents of the directory.

Comment: @user1103897
`configure: error: PAM enabled but headers or library not found, install the PAM development support or run configure --without-pam
`
The above line is important. Google search for info on how to install the PAM development headers for your distro.

Answer (score 1):

You should install the correct libraries for pam and readline:
The PAM libraries are needed for the PAM plugin.

On the Centos and RHEL -build VMs, install the pam-devel package:

```
sudo yum install pam-devel
```

On all the Debian/Ubuntu -build virtual machines, install libpam0g-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libpam0g-dev
```

On debian6/maverick/natty, install libreadline5-dev (replacing any libreadline6-dev already there):

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline5-dev
```

On oneiric (and any newer, eg. Debian 7 or Ubuntu 12.04), the package is called libreadline-gplv2-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev
```